# Как выполнить условие если число вхождений подстроки в строку больше чем?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такой запрос в Mysql

```
SELECT a.`product_id`, c.`name`, c.`tag`, (CHAR_LENGTH(c.`tag`) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(c.`tag`,',',''))) div CHAR_LENGTH(',') as counts
FROM `table`
```

Как добавить условие, что если результат больше 5?

```
(CHAR_LENGTH(c.`tag`) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(c.`tag`,',',''))) div CHAR_LENGTH(',') > 5
```

Т. е. что-то вида, извините уж за такой кривой пример

```
SELECT a.`product_id`, c.`name`, c.`tag`, (CHAR_LENGTH(c.`tag`) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(c.`tag`,',',''))) div CHAR_LENGTH(',') as counts
FROM `table`
WHERE (CHAR_LENGTH(c.`tag`) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(c.`tag`,',',''))) div CHAR_LENGTH(',') > 5
```

Comment: а так как вы написали не работает?

Comment: Да что то не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Протестировал Ваш запрос на `w3schools`, вроде бы работает. Подставил свои значения

```
SELECT 1, "test" as name, "tag,asd" as tag, ((CHAR_LENGTH('tag,asd') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('tag,asd',',',''))) div CHAR_LENGTH(',')) as counts
from Customers
WHERE ((CHAR_LENGTH('tag,asd') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('tag,asd',',',''))) div CHAR_LENGTH(',')) > 5
```

Все, что сделал - это обернул дополнительно в скобки содержимое перед `as counts` и перед `> 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не переписывать выражение, можно использовать алиас поля выходного набора, переместив условие в секцию HAVING.

```
SELECT a.`product_id`, 
       c.`name`, 
       c.`tag`, 
       (CHAR_LENGTH(c.`tag`) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(c.`tag`,',',''))) DIV CHAR_LENGTH(',') AS counts
FROM `table` 
HAVING counts > 5
```